# Not able to send SMS from my Lumia 640 XL LTE?

Tags: 8.1, sms, lumia-640-xl

I bought a new Lumia 640 XL LTE and after inserting SIM, I am able to call and receive SMS but not able to send text messages. Can anyone suggest what might be the issue and do I need to change any settings for that?

Software Version: Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2
OS Version: 8.10.15148.160

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you been able to try the SIM in a different phone? Can you get your service provider to push the service centre settings to you?

Comment: No I don't get error message. Also, i got settings from my service provider.  But i have not tried to check same on different phone

Comment: Can you try sending an MMS (like, send a photo message) instead? In theory, MMS shouldn't work if SMS isn't working, but in theory if you can make calls over a digital network (and modern phones don't support anything but digital) then you should be able to send SMS.

Answer (score 2):

Not everyone is facing this type of problem.Can not receive or send text message,then check your messaging setting and, if you don't get your problem solved, then do upgrade/update your phone.Then you should able to send new message, from the new messaging app.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I registered a complaint against my network provider and they did reset the SMS settings and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I could receive but **not send** texts on Lumia 640.   Resolved "problem" by turning completely OFF...waiting...then turning back on.   A tech told me it's good to turn COMPLETELY OFF every few days, if you customarily have phone ON most of the time.