# No settings visible under "Mobile & SIM"

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-640-xl

I just bought a new Lumia 640XL. It works OK with my existing SIM, except SMS messages do not appear to work when sending receiving from overseas.

When I look at settings under Mobile & SIM, there is nothing there.  My phone was delivered with a bunch of AT&T software. Could it be somehow blocked by AT&T?  How can I unlock it? Though I can phone my contacts.... weird.

Just noticed there's also an ATT logo when I boot the phone.

UPDATE: rebooted the phone based on an answer [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/11957/not-able-to-send-sms-from-my-lumia-640-xl-lte) and can now see SIM settings. But I still see the ATT logo on startup. Can I get rid of that?

Thanks for any help